# TKinter app - not showing frames in oop approach

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Something must have gone wrong in my TKinter project when I restructured the code to conform to the OOP paradigm.

The MainFrame is no longer displayed. I would expect a red frame after running the code below, but it just shows a blank window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("App")
        self.geometry("800x600")

        main_frame = MainFrame(self)
        main_frame.tkraise()


class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure("top_frame.TFrame", background="red")
        self.my_frame = ttk.Frame(self, style="top_frame.TFrame")
        self.my_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You never called `.pack()` or any other geometry manager on `main_frame`, so there's no possibility for its child Frame to be visible.

Comment: Thank you - adding
    ```self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)```
in the init-function of the MainFrame-class resolved the issue.

Comment: @jasonharper It looks to me like the `Frame` that's a child of the `MainFrame` class is `pack`ed on `__init__`: `self.my_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`, but since `MainFrame` inherits from `ttk.Frame` itself, I think you're probably right. I'm not sure what OP gains from this inheritence, however.

Comment: @JRiggles: yes, `my_frame` is packed, but every ancestor widget all the way back to the root window also has to be packed (or otherwise managed) for that to make any difference.

Comment: @jasonharper Yep, that would do it!

Comment: What is the point of creating an inner frame (`self.my_frame`) that totally covers its parent frame (`MainFrame`)?

Comment: There are actually several frames in my application, I reduced it just for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also manage the geometry of your `MainFrame` inside the App, for example by packing it:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("App")
        self.geometry("800x600")

        main_frame = MainFrame(self)
        main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)  # PACKING FRAME
        main_frame.tkraise()


class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure("top_frame.TFrame", background="red")
        self.my_frame = ttk.Frame(self, style="top_frame.TFrame")
        self.my_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()
```